# comments for nextflow script shell commands inside triple quotes

Tags: groovy, comments, nextflow

I want to add comments to the shell commands run in an nextflow process. For example

```
process A_MSC {
    tag "${ comp_id }"
    label (params.LABEL)
    publishDir params.OUTPUT,  mode: 'copy'
   
    input:
    file(reference)
   
    output:
    tuple val(comp_id), path("*.{gz,npy}"), emit: plots


    script:
    """
    echo "==========================="
    echo "Need a comment here"

    """
}
```

So what would be the comment character for where the echo line is placed
For comments outside those script section , one would use // or /* but if I use them inside the shell script triple quotes, those cause failures.

Comment: The code between the """ is bash so it should be the standard bash way of doing comments, prrefix the line with a hashtag: #My comment goes here